# Java - Pass Response Time From Android Studio Into 'phpmyadmin'

Tags: java, android-studio, phpmyadmin

**I**'m developing brain games currently. I try to get the response time from the game using a chronometer. This is the code:

```
 private void showElapsedTime()
        {
            long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                    - simpleChronometer.getBase();

            elapsedMillis = elapsedMillis/1000;
            String response_time = Long.toString(elapsedMillis);

            Toast.makeText(PictureEasy.this,
                    "Time taken: " + response_time +" second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I then try to pass the response time into 'phpmyadmin' using this:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_time", response_time));
```

But the value in 'phpmyadmin' only shows 00:00:00. By the way, I'd also like to clarify that the datatype for response_time in 'phpmyadmin' is time.

Comment: Store it as an integer, not a time.

Comment: i've change it. the actual value is 2 seconds but in 'phpmyadmin' it shows 0.